# My question got closed (as a duplicate)

Tags: support

My [question](https://superuser.com/questions/1693093/get-the-windows-10-code-name-via-cli) got closed as a duplicate (I think by a single mod, not by the community)... the question it linked to, did not contain the answer I specified in my question. I already added comments as well as an additional note in the question. I would be glad if s.o. would reopen it. Thanks.

Comment: A single moderator represents the entire community.  [Had your question been clear to begin with it wouldn't have been closed.](https://superuser.com/revisions/1693093/1)

Comment: By community I meant community vote (4 votes, or how much it takes to close)

Comment: I knew what you meant, I just wanted to make it clear, a moderator closing a question just as much represents the community's view than the actual community since the the moderator was elected by the community.  I would have voted to close your question (per it's first revision) by the way as the exact same duplicate more than likely.

Answer (score 1):

done, thanks to whom ever reopend it.

Comment: [A community user and a community moderator was the reason your question was reopened.](https://superuser.com/posts/1693093/timeline)

Comment: thx for the info!